# Is it possible to detect if a script is being loaded as a RequireJS module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm researching whether there is a way to detect, *for sure*, whether a given script is currently being loaded by RequireJS.  An answer for AMD modules in general would be even better, but my use case is only RequireJS.

jQuery and other libraries "detect" it like so:

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

That is sufficient in most cases, but the problem is that it doesn't detect whether the script is being loaded as an AMD module, it only detects whether `define` exists and supports the AMD spec.

Is there a way, either with RequireJS or with AMD modules in general, for a script to determine (for real) whether it is being loaded as a module?

Comment: The method you've shown is detecting an AMD loader by duck-typing. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @RobW It detects the presence of an AMD loader perfectly.  It does not detect whether the script is *being loaded* as an AMD module.  At a higher level, the code above will return true if `<script src="require.js"></script>` exists, regardless of whether a given script is actually being loaded with RequireJS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [specified()](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apiload):

> parentRequire.specified(moduleName): Returns true if the module has
>   already been requested or is in the process of loading and should be
>   available at some point.

```
if (typeof require === "function" && typeof require.specified === "function" && require.specified("jquery")) {
    define("jquery", [], function () {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

Now the problematic thing is how to get the module name because it may differ depending on the user setup. There is a [special module for that](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#wiki-module), but that works only if you are already in a define call. I recommend you contact [jrburke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126372/jrburke) who is the Requirejs developer.

Comment: I'd change `typeof require === "function" && require.specified("jquery")` with `typeof require === "function" && typeof require.specified === "function" && require.specified("jquery")`

Comment: This is helpful but, IMHO, it still doesn't fully answer the question as it requires you to know the module name. Since RequireJS allows the user to configure those, I'd prefer to not have to hard-code it here but rather `define` the module anonymously if possible. :(

Comment: I've added this question to the RequireJS mailing list, hoping for better info:  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/requirejs/iDnC4Cda7UQ/discussion